# Integrate Android OkHttp3 with NewRelic

Tags: android, newrelic, okhttp

I'm using OkHttp version 3.1.2 (Can't change version cause latest picasso and retrofit library) and set up through tutorial NewRelic library version 5.4.1 (as said in tutorial it supports okhttp2.1+). And NewRelic successfully handled crashes, but it doesn't handle http transaction. "Harvester" always logs "Sending 0 HTTP transactions". But when trying to use NewRelic.noticeHttpTransaction it send analytics.

How can I bind okhttp3.1+ with NewRelic, is it possible? Or maybe I did something wrong, cause I think that NR should automatically handle http requests/errors?

Comment: I am having the same issue as your, after moving to okhttp, newrelic doesn't reports any http transactions.

Answer (score 0):

It's possible now,

[Android agent](https://discuss.newrelic.com/t/support-okhttp-3-on-android/32966/10), as of version 5.8.3, auto-instruments OkHttp3,
Also [Java agent](https://docs.newrelic.com/docs/agents/java-agent/getting-started/compatibility-requirements-java-agent#frameworks) is supporting OkHttp3

> OkHttp 3.0 to 3.6